# Installation of packages Pycharm 64-bit fails

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I was previously on the path on working towards being able to obtain SEC 10K filings from Edgar, wherein I used a bloggers code for inspiration. When running this code in Pycharm 32-bit, I kept getting a "MemoryError" - which as far as I know is related to not having enough RAM (since 32-bit can only use 4GB).. I have 8GB of DDR3, so I figured if I installed Pycharm 64-bit, I should be ok!

However, when trying to set up the 64-bit version, and installing the same packages that I used previously in order to run the code again, I get the following error:

```
Collecting python-edgar
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/5d/88b7c392cf9d69c61b418f9f5851292b52964fcde8f3116b2256e2fde5fa/python-edgar-2.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\PPB92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-82zmyasf\python-edgar\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        long_description=read('README.md'),
      File "C:\Users\PPB92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-82zmyasf\python-edgar\setup.py", line 6, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\PPB92\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-82zmyasf\\python-edgar\\README.md'
```

Does anyone know what I can do? I have very limited experience in programming, since I am a graduate student in finance and accounting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is problem in library itself, i have raised the issue on git.
For now you can do:

```
git clone git@github.com:edouardswiac/python-edgar.git
```

in your site-packages and under python-edgar folder run :

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I forgot to reply, I am sorry. Thank you for raising the issue, your solution back then worked flawlessly!